# How to fix Ubuntu classic on 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, unity, panel

When I change from Unity to the classic desktop, the panels are there INCLUDING UNITY. Is there a way to fix and remove Unity from classic desktop? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load up CompizConfig Settings Manager (`ccsm` from the terminal - `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` if you don't have it installed). Then just search for the Unity plugin and disable it by unchecking its box.

- Warning: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)